# 0-3.3V to 0-5V step by step

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, dac, 5v, 3.3v

I have a 3.3V microcontroller. I want to use dac. I will work 0-5V range. But my microcontroller has max voltage 3.3v. I want to use a amplifier. I wait your recommendation.

note: how can i this. Similarly operational amplifikator but i want use currently method. so i need a help but i don't know any method because i am mechanical student.

Comment: You can't ask shopping questions on this site. Sorry.

Comment: do you know any this module name. ı just ask this. sory

Comment: please check  your  evaluation. after my edit.

Comment: We don't suggest or recommend modules etc. here. That's because such answers are irrelevant to other users and the purpose of this site is to answer questions which are relevant to others as well. Also, it is very unclear what you're trying to achieve, I strongly suggest that you get help from someone with some experience in electronics.

Comment: okey. i edit my quastion. i wait your advice.

Comment: I have two questions that I fail to understand from your question. 1. Do you need to convert any DC analog signal ranging from 0-3.3V into 0-5V? Or you want the microcontroller to output 0-5V? It's a different problem. 2. Do you want the output to be clean DC or PWM?

Comment: [Non inverting op-amp](https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/analogue_circuits/operational-amplifier-op-amp/non-inverting-amplifier.php)

Comment: Why use an amplifier a simple two resistor voltage divider should do the job

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to get the DAC output from 3.3V up to 5V. The opamp below scales the DAC output from 3.3V up to 5V.  Opamp needs to be rail-to-rail input and output and 5V rated.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzHigA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Judging by the level of the question you need to point out to the OP that the op-amp requires rail-to-rail output, negative rail input capability and 5 V operation.

Comment: As @Transistor said, it's should be better to increase V2 to arround 7V (or more). Even with a rail to rail capability, 5V will never be possible.

Comment: op did not indicate that a 7V rail was available.  This is the best they can do with the rails they have.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you have a 0 - 5 V analog signal that you wish to input to a 0 - 3.3 V analog input.

> I want to use a amplifier.

You don't need one. You want to *reduce* the signal. You can do this with a "potential divider".

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fn28qs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A 5:3.3 potential divider.*

I have chosen those values of resistors to make the mathematics easy. You can change the values if you keep the ratios the same. If you make the resistances too low you might overload the input voltage and pull it down. If you make the resistance too high then the analog input might pull the voltage down. The values I have given should be about right.

Comment: my input 0-3.3V range. i want to output voltage set 0-5V range.i am sorry for my engilish.

Comment: Please edit your question and add in part numbers and datasheet links for your controllers. Is the analog out a real DAC or is it PWM?